# remove single cronjob from crontab

Tags: cron, debian

I have a script that needs to be triggered every day at random times. The times the script needs to run are generated at midnight and stored in a mysql database. Occasionally on some days no times are generated and the script doesn't need to be triggered.

the entries can look like this:

```
+----------------+----------------------------+
| Date           | Times                      |
|----------------+----------------------------+
| 2020-06-13     | 07:13, 14:48               |
| 2020-06-14     |                            |
| 2020-06-15     | 09:00, 09:26, 17:01, 17:42 |
+----------------+----------------------------+
```

I'm using php to grab the times and split them up in crontab format since I figured it might be the easiest way to run the script. I can generate something like this:

```
00 09 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/apps/control/trigger.php
26 09 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/apps/control/trigger.php
01 17 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/apps/control/trigger.php
42 17 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/apps/control/trigger.php
```

this would work, if I need to run them daily at these times. is there a way to remove the like when the script ran successfully? I cannot really use `crontab -r` to clear the jobs because there are other crontasks planned too.

The server i'm working on is a debian server.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I've never found any really satisfactory answer to this. In the past, I have added a `uuid` as a dummy, ignored parameter to the script, then you can run `crontab -l | grep -v UUID` to get a *"cleaned"* crontab to which you can append your new material.

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for your comment. I created a second user just for this purpose to be honest. this might actually do the trick just fine. with this I'll be able to delete old cronjobs from the user and create now one at midnight too. odd solution, but it might work as intendent.